# asp.net core async controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, microservices, pool

My project is built with microservice architecture. Cosider this:
I have two services. The first one is used for long-running operation run in background. It sends data of processing when it operates by chunks to another service - **Aggregator**. 
Now I have that Aggregator stays for some time but I want it to be used to the limit of its possibilities. 
Is the same time, I would like to perform several requests to the first service in the same time, so the both services should use one Aggregator. I guess, that can be done using *pool*.
Could you please provide me with an example of the code how to do this or even with better idea?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: This is no code-providing platform. You should try by yourself and ask if something isn't working properly.

Comment: Understood. Thank you